# phpunit testing with sqlite and laravel eloquent

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, phpunit, eloquent

I have a package that uses DB, and I wanted to create some tests that will run with sqlite in memory for the tests.

Now I have this base test class:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;

class TestCaseDb extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    protected $db;
    protected $tbmsg;
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp(); // //DONT CARE
        League\FactoryMuffin\Facade::getFaker()->unique($reset = true);//DONT CARE
        $this->initDb();
        $this->initTbmsg(); //DONT CARE
    }

    protected function initDb() {
        //confi gfor the sqlite
        $capsule = new Manager();
        $capsule->addConnection([
            'driver'    => 'sqlite',
            'database'  => ':memory:',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ]);
        $capsule->setAsGlobal();
        $capsule->bootEloquent();
        $this->db = $capsule->getDatabaseManager();

        //loading simple DB tables creation
        $importSql = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/dumps/dump.sql');
        $this->db->statement($importSql);


    }
}
```

Now as you can see here I create the sqlite database and create the eloquent DB object for handling it.

But, now if I query it with the

```
 $this->db->select("whatever");
```

it works great.

But when I try to use an Eloquent object so it will tell me that the specific table doesn't exist. (It exists 100% in the first Db)

So I think that eloquent model tries to connect to another DB connection and not for the one I created.

IE - this is the test that gives the error:

```
class SimpleTest extends TestCaseDb  {
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function first() {
        //the below row works!
        //$this->db->insert('insert into conv_users (conv_id, user_id) values (?, ?)', array(1, 2));

        //the insert with Eloquent fails....
        $data = League\FactoryMuffin\Facade::create('Tzookb\TBMsg\Models\Eloquent\Conversation', []);
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

You can see the code in my github package as well: (branch dev)
https://github.com/tzookb/tbmsg/tree/dev/tests

Answer (score 5):

What you are doing is unnecessary.

Laravel provides you with tools out of the box to do what you are trying to do already.

Add this in your `setUp()` of `TestCase`.

```php
Artisan::call('migrate');

$this->seed();
```

It will migrate your migrations in your SQLite memory database.

You should have something like this then:

```
<?php

class TestCase extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase {

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        Artisan::call('migrate');

        $this->seed();
    }

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $unitTesting = true;

        $testEnvironment = 'testing';       

        return require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/start.php';
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not tests inside laravel, it is a package for laravel. I use the sqlite for testing my package

Comment: thanks I know that :) but I'm not inside the scope of laravel project, this is only for testing the package, it is not relevant for laravel, it is a package for laravel and uses it's DB unit but the tests run outside the scope of it.